# histogram categorized data in c#

Tags: c#, histogram, math.net

I am using numerics.mathdotnet to calculate the histogram of sorted data.
My dataset looks as following

row1,a,b,c

row2,x,y,z

...

and my histogram is calculated, let's say on column 4 which has  [c,z,...].
After the histogram generation and plotted onto a graph (x-axis: buckets, y-axis: count of rows in that bucket), i want to get the rows that fall into a particular bucket.

My solution:
I pass the start and end of bucket (calculated using bucket width) to function, iterate over all the rows and check if that row falls within the bucket range.

Problem: For some bucket widths, it shows count to be > 0 but when I fetch it does not find any rows within that bucket.

Question: Is there any way to get the data along with histogram results?
eg: { bucketRange_start: x, bucketRange_end: y, count: n, data: [...] }

Answer (score 0):

Sample program:

```
 // try Histogram
            //using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics; // required header

            // create random data
            Random RanGen = new Random();
            double[][] d = new double[4][];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) d[i] = new double[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) d[i][j] = RanGen.NextDouble(); }

            // create histogram for 3rd array = d[2] ;
            Histogram h2 = new Histogram(d[2], 10);

            // write bucket info including max, min and count
            for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) Console.WriteLine(h2[b].ToString());

            // Write row number and row data for all rows for which d3 value is in bucket with index = 7;
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                if (h2.GetBucketIndexOf(d[2][j]) == 7) Console.WriteLine(j + "  " + d[0][j].ToString() + "  " + d[1][j].ToString() + "  " + d[2][j].ToString() + "  " + d[3][j].ToString() + "  ");
            }
```